# Can not deploy Entries in Entities to DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, jovo-framework

I'm currently working with Custom Entities (Developer Entities) via modifying [Entities JSON Docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities#top_of_page)

I **know how to create & link manually my Custom Entities with my Intents**.

[image]

I had

`en-US.json` with customized entities (Valid json)

```
{
"invocation": "Test",
"intents": [
  ...
],
"dialogflow": {
    "intents": [
        {
            "name": "Default Fallback Intent",
            "auto": true,
            "webhookUsed": true,
            "fallbackIntent": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Default Welcome Intent",
            "auto": true,
            "webhookUsed": true,
            "events": [
                {
                    "name": "WELCOME"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "entities": [
        {
            "id": "f060b6f7-7a17-4355-9fa6-3ce02f0ce33a",
            "name": "additionalTopic",
            "isOverridable": true,
            "entries": [
                {
                    "synonyms": [
                        "usuk",
                        "us",
                        "uk",
                        "us music",
                        "uk music",
                        "play usuk",
                        "play us",
                        "play uk",
                        "play us music",
                        "play uk music"
                    ],
                    "value": "usuk"
                },
                {
                    "synonyms": [
                        "vn",
                        "vietnamese"
                    ],
                    "value": "vn"
                }
            ],
            "isEnum": false,
            "automatedExpansion": false
        }
    ]
}
```

It **looks like correct** as [Entities JSON Docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent/entities#top_of_page)

I build with jovo command line : `jovo build`

It generated `additionalTopic.json` & `additionalTopic_usersays_en.json` in folder `platforms/googleAction/dialogflow/entities`, as image

[image]

**These steps in above looks like OK**, right?

Then I deploy to DialogFlow via jovo command line : `jovo deploy --project-id PROJECT_ID`

It **deployed success** as usually.

Last steps I going to [DialogFlow Console](https://console.dialogflow.com) to check Custom Entities I created,

And here it is.

[image]

`Entities name` appeared, but where is `synonyms`?

What **I want is after deployed, it expects as first image** in above.

Please take a look and help me find the way,

Really thanks.

p/s : I'm using DialogFlow Console version 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is the bug in `jovo-framework`.

In this time, `jovo-framework` only support for DialogFlow version 1.

jovo releases note : https://github.com/jovotech/jovo-framework-nodejs/releases

Comment: Jovo Framework has been supporting Dialogflow API version 2 for several months.